# trying to play random video from list as background

Tags: html, video

fairly new to HTML so I need some help. I am trying to play a random video as the background to my website. I have the video part playing already, but I want it to pick a random video from the directory and play that every time the page loads

This is partial code for playing the video

```
<source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

The "1.mp4" is what I am trying to change every time the page loads. I have a folder in the directory called "bg" where I have a few other videos stored, labeled 1.mp4, 2.mp4 and so on until 5.mp4. I cant figure out how to randomly pick one of those videos, and set it as the source in the code above.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add some simple JavaScript. Full code below:

```html
<source src="" id="RandomVid" type="video/mp4">
<script>
    window.onload = function(event) {
        
    document.getElementById("RandomVid").src = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1).toString() + ".mp4";
  
  //Remove the code below in the real thing
  alert(document.getElementById('RandomVid').src);

    }
</script>
```

Remove `alert(document.getElementById('RandomVid').src);` 
in your real thing, because it's only a test to show you which video is playing.

**Explanation**:

`window.onload` triggers the code when the window is fully loaded.

`document.getElementById("RandomVid").src`  gets the src attribute for RandomVid.

`Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)` gets a randowm number between 1 ~ 5.

`.toString() + ".mp4"` makes the random number a string and adds ".mp4" at the end

This is the example that I ran on my computer(**Please look at the Right Hand and the src attribute**)
[image: This is an example]

Comment: not sure if im doing it wrong or if it doesnt work but I pasted exactly what you have and only the first video is playing, none of the others

Comment: Try again, is it still the same output?

Comment: this is what i have in my code https://i.imgur.com/o4XaG3m.png

Comment: Try to leave the src attribute empty at first, like this: `<source src="" id="RandomVid" type="video/mp4">`

Comment: No problem! By the way, change `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)` to `Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)`, in case that the random number becomes 0